# tf.estimator package not installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

My `tensorflow-gpu` was running fine before. But now it is giving me this error:

```
tf.estimator package not installed.
```

when import is invoked:

```
user@pc:~/workspace$ python
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
tf.estimator package not installed.
tf.estimator package not installed.
>>>
```

I have googled it and installed `pandas` and `matplotlib` as suggested in [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23007) link but is still did not work.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by running the following command:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow-estimator
```

This command uninstalled the conflicting version of tensorflow-estimator.

The version of tensorflow_gpu installed is `tensorflow_gpu-1.12.0` and the conflicting estimator version was: `tensorflow-estimator-1.13.0`.

So, the above command removed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I followed it mostyl, but the virtual environment does not seem to work.

When executing

```
c:\> virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python3 ./venv
```

I get

```
virtualenv : The term 'virtualenv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python3 ./venv
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (virtualenv:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

when instead executing

```
py virtualenv.py  --system-site-packages -p python3 ./venv
```

I get

```
The path python3 (from --python=python3) does not exist
C:\users\movgp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python
```

So far, I am unsure if the manual for installing on Windows is fully complete. Also, I think that it should work without the virtual environment too.

I suspect it might be a problem with the path length, since Python was installed to

```
C:\users\movgp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\
```

rather than the usual (but inappropriate) path

```
C:\Python37\
```